# Issue with first PHP program

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm trying to use the here document and store it in a variable. The problem is in notepad++ the here document comments everything below the initialization line, including the closing tag for the PHP file. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
     $html = <<<HTMLBLOCK
         Hello world
     HTMLBLOCK;
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heredocs are whitespace aware. You need to close the tag at the very left:

```
<?php
     $html = <<<HTMLBLOCK
         Hello world
HTMLBLOCK;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to write it that way:

```
<?php
   $html = <<<HTMLBLOCK
   Hello world
HTMLBLOCK;
?>
```

notice the HTMLBLOCK without padding-left? :)